# get rowdata innerHTML input value of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, innerhtml

I have a basic HTML table containing static value with the exception of just one cell, which contains an input field.

I am grabbing the rowdata and converting it to JSON, but the single input field is causing problems.

Without the input field, I can successfully grab all of the static values and turn them into a JSON object, as follows:

```
var table = document.getElementById('locationdetailsBody');
var locationjsonArr = [];
for(var i =0,row;row = table.rows[i];i++){
   var col = row.cells;
   var jsonObj = {
        currlocation : $.trim(col[0].innerHTML),
        currlocationname : $.trim(col[1].innerHTML),
        currlocationoperator : $.trim(col[2].innerHTML)
    }

  locationjsonArr.push(jsonObj);
}
```

The above code works, until I add .val() to the innertHTML of currlocation:

```
currlocation : $.trim(col[0].innerHTML.val()),
```

The output error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: col[0].innerHTML.val is not a function
```

I need to be able to grab the user entered value of the input field and add it to the JSON.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `col[0]` is a reference to the `td` of your table, then you can use `querySelector()` to retrieve the child `input` to retrieve its `value`.

Also note that using jQuery only for `$.trim()` is a little wasteful. You could use the native `trim()` function and remove the reliance on jQuery entirely. In addition you can use `map()` to build the array more succinctly:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('locationdetailsBody');
var locationjsonArr = Array.from(table.rows).map(row => ({
  currlocation: row.cells[0].querySelector('input').value.trim(),
  currlocationname: row.cells[1].innerHTML.trim(),
  currlocationoperator: row.cells[2].innerHTML.trim()
}));

console.log(locationjsonArr);
```

```html
<table id="locationdetailsBody">
  <tr>
    <td><input value="lorem" /></td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is for `<input>` and `<textarea>` value, if you want to get text content of element (without tag) use `.text()` or `innerText` for vanilla JS

Comment: This did not work for me.  I did not downvote you, but I will upvote you for helping me out.  Thank you.

Comment: it is  may be downvoted because I miss to add `col[1].innerText` but no problem, thanks.